# Read text file looking for a specific word, copying all lines in that group

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Pure vb noob..I am trying to read and write data to a file when found.  I used the following code to get the files. I can get the files to a listbox for now, but really needed to find files search though them for a specific word and copy that data.

```
For Each foundfile As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\tmp\logsd", "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If foundfile.Contains("un") Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(foundfile)
    End If
Next
```

Once I find all the files I need to search through all those text files and find a specific word.

The text file similar to this

```
19-Jan-2015 22:50:52.425
Green:1
Red:-1
Apples:1
Blue:2
Yellow:2
```

```
20-Jan-2015 22:50:52.425
Green:1
Red:-1
Pears:1
Blue:2
Yellow:2
```

```
20-Jan-2015 22:50:52.425
Green:1
Red:-1
Apples:1
Blue:2
Yellow:2
```

So if I where to search for Apples it would find 2 instances of it and copy all those lines to a text file.

```
19-Jan-2015 22:50:52.425
Green:1
Red:-1
Apples:1
Blue:2
Yellow:2
```

```
20-Jan-2015 22:50:52.425
Green:1
Red:-1
Apples:1
Blue:2
Yellow:2
```

I tired using streamreader but I can only seem to get the one line to show.

```
Using reader As New StreamReader(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        If line.Contains("Apples") Then
            '????????
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: You want to see if the file contains the word "Apples" and if so, then append the *entire* contents of that file to another output file?  (as opposed to just copying the one line that contains the word)

Comment: Your current code exits the loop after the first instance is found - when you check the text, if the line contains what you're looking for, you call `Exit While`.   Remove that line and it should capture all the instances.

Comment: As @Tim said, remove `Exit While` to have your code find all the instances. As for what to do when you find the word. Add either your line or the current file (whichever you want) to the file/list you're using to keep track of found instances. `foundList.Add(line)` or something similar.

Comment: Actually, there's a bigger issue in the code.  `reader.ReadToEnd()` is being used, so it's grabbing the entire file at once.  Better to use `reader.ReadLine()`, or even better use `File.ReadAllLines()` which will dump the contents of the file into a `String()` (String array).  Then you can check for the word you're looking for and add that line (or the lines around it) to the `List(Of String)`.

Comment: Steven Doggart If the file has the words apples in it, find all instances and copy them to a new file. Tim and Jdkorv11 Ill take your advise and try to see what I can come up with thanks for the direction and help.  Will post results soon.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some messing around I got it to do what I wanted but seems like a real bad way of doing it.

```
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
Dim LineCounter As Integer = 0

Using reader As New StreamReader(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)

    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        LineCounter = LineCounter + 1

        If line = "apples:1" Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter - 4))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter - 3))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter - 2))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter - 1))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 1))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 2))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 3))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 4))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 5))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 6))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 7))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 8))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 9))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 10))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(lines(LineCounter + 11))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(" ")

        End If

    End While

End Using
```

Comment: This ought to be an edit to your question. I've formatted the code for you.